# How to color one of a 100 boxes with a button in a modal using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Just to make it easier Im explaining what I wish to do in a simplified example.

- I have 100 boxes on my site using simple html/css. (styling not shown)
- I have written a bit of JS to open a modal that opens when clicking on one of the 100 boxes carrying the same class: class="boxes":

The modal has an Id of "modal":

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var boxesLength = boxes.length;
```

When any box is clicked the modal appears:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++) {
    boxes[i].onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    };
    }
```

- Now I wish to color the box  that was clicked using a button in the modal that was opened. The code that doesn't work but is my closest guess looks like this:

  ```
  //get the coloring button in the modal which has Id of "green".

  var coloring = document.getElementById("green");

  coloring.onclick = function () {
  boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#90EE90";
  //closing the modal after clicking which works
  modal.style.display = "none";
  };
  ```

Writing "boxes[0]" will color the first box, but that is of course not what I wish. I wish to color the box that was clicked.

Thank you for any input. Good day!

***on request ive added som simple html***

```
    //The modal
    <div id="modal">
            <button id="green">Completed</button>
    </div>

    //just some boxes         
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    .... 96 more boxes
```

Comment: Your HTML code would be helpful. Add it here bro

Comment: Ive added some now, and updated the post so its more clear now. Thank you :) @KhalidKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance to how I understood your issue.You want the background color to show on the box that was clicked for it to show the modal.
Here is my solution.

```js
//to pass it as a global variable between functions
var randomv = {}
 var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
 var close = document.querySelector('.close')

//get all box
var x = document.getElementById("innerBox").querySelectorAll(".box");
  //for each box execute the following
  x.forEach(box => {
    //on clicking each box, execute a function
    box.addEventListener("click", function () {
      //this references the parent element which in this case is the box
      randomv.parent = this
      //display the modal on clicking the box
      modal.style.display = "block";
    })
  });
  
//hide the modal on clicking the x
close.addEventListener("click", function(){
 modal.style.display = "none"
}); 


  function changeColor() {
  //first ensure the background color is normal for each box
    x.forEach(box => {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
  //reserve the parent element to a variable
    var parent_div = randomv.parent
   //change the parent's bg color
    parent_div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
</script>
```

```css
  #modal {
      display: none;
    }

    #innerBox {
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      
     
    }
    .box{
      flex-grow: 1;
     
    }
    .close,.box{
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
  
    <div id="modal">model content
      <div class="close"> x </div>
      <button onclick="changeColor()">green</button>
    </div>
    <div id="innerBox">
      <div class="box 1">box1</div>
      <div class="box 2">box2</div>
      <div class="box 3">box3</div>
      <div class="box 4">box4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is here. You have: `for (var i = 0; i < btnsLength; i++) {`, but should be referring to `boxesLength` so `for (var i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++`.

This would be an ideal application for 'event delegation'. Read more here: https://javascript.info/event-delegation.

Essentially you put the click handler on the parent container for all of your boxes and then use `target` to point to the clicked box. That gives you 1 event handler instead of 100.

Comment: Thank you for your time. That was a simple mistake that is not solving anything. Sorry! :) Ive have updated the post for several mistakes now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes unfortunately. The mistake I had here was only here. Not in my original code. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using "this":

```
    for (var i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++) {
      boxes[i].onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        var koko = this;
        green.onclick = function () {
          koko.style.backgroundColor = "#90EE90";
          modal.style.display = "none";
        };
      };
```